# How to update Azure Data Factory live mode from Git branches?

Tags: git, azure-data-factory

My ADF configuration is as follows:

- The Main branch is used to push all our latest changes from individual branches.
- The Collaboration branch is empty and set as the "collaboration" branch in ADF.
- There is an outdated live mode with old pipelines that I want to remove and replace with the content of the Main branch.

[image]

My first need is to be able to set ADF triggers in my ADF instance. From my understanding, it is only possible in the live mode. Therefore, I need to update the live mode with the latest changes from my Git repo (Main branch)

My issue is that the Collaboration branch is the only place where I can find the "Overwrite Live mode" button. As specified above, the problem is that Collaboration branch is empty and doesn't contain any pipelines today. The Main branch contains all the up-to-date pipelines.

What should be the best approach here? Should I disconnect Git and reconnect it, setting the Main branch as the collaboration branch? And then push "Overwrite Live Mode"?

Or is there a way to change the collaboration branch to "main"?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be, as you said, to disconnect, and then reconnect again, this time setting "main" as the collaboration branch. Note not to import the live mode while reconnecting, to not overwrite your main branch.

Another option is to do a pull request from "main" branch to the "collaboration" branch, which will then include all changes and then do a publish, or overwrite live mode. This will fix your environment for now, but you are likely to get the same issue again with future developments.